# make python os.chdir follow vim autochdir?

Tags: python, vim

I use the autochdir option in VIM and I also utilize VIM's built-in Python interface. Is it possible to have the current directory for the built-in Python interpreter follow VIM's autochdir. For example, when I am editing  a Python file, VIM's autochdir option puts me in the same directory as the edited file as far as VIM is concerned, but I still have to manually

```
 :py os.chdir(directory)
```

from the VIM command line in order to get the Python interpreter to recognize the same directory that VIM has.

Is this possible? I'm using VIM 7.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try putting in vimrc

```
autocmd Filetype python py os.chdir(directory)
```

which means that whenever a python file is read or written, it executes this command.

Comment: Then, if I switch between open buffers,  where each buffer contains a different Python file in a different directory, will it restore the  respective directory upon switching?

Comment: autocmd Bufenter *.py py os.chdir(directory) should run the command whenever you switch a buffer

Comment: Brilliant! here's the full command for the vimrc

 autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile,Bufenter *.py py os.chdir(vim.eval("expand('%:p:h')"))